# Openskynetwork API

Tags: reactjs, rest

Please i need help on this:

Using the OpenskyAPI, create a ReactJS login and component dashboard that shows all the flights arriving and departing from all airports

in this format AIRPORT | TIME | arriving | departing

e.g  DFW | 15:00 PM CST | 50 | 32

Comment: Please who knows any api i can get a list of all airports, country and icao codes?  kindly share.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.